# Is there such a thing as an Asynchronous SQL query?

Tags: sql, asynchronous

By this I mean if I am running a query that will return a million results, can I return a thousand at a time and append, much like how an AJAX call will return results and append to HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own with the `TOP` function in MSSQL or the `LIMIT` in MySQL. Alter your query to return a maximum of 1000 records, and keep a running start index.

Appending to HTML will be a different problem. Perhaps your best option is to make a function that gets paged data on the server, and call this multiple times from the client.